# How to input 8 byte hexadecimal number into char array?

Tags: c

I want to generate sequence of hexadecimal numbers starting with `07060504003020100`.
Next number would be `0f0e0d0c0b0a0908` etc in that order.

When I use `unsigned long long int` and output the data the first 4 bits, meaning that `0` is truncated. and it prints `706050403020100`.

So I was thinking of putting the number into a `char` array buffer(or some other buffer) and then print the output so that later if I want to compare I can do character/byte wise compare.

Can anybody help me out? `char[8]="0x0706050403020100"` doesn't look right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What are you using to print out your value?  The syntax for printing 8 0-padded bytes to stdout would be something like

```
printf("%016X", value);
```

It breaks down like this:

```
%x    = lowercase hex
%X    = uppercase hex
%16X  = always 16 characters (adds spaces)
%016X = zero-pad so that the result is always 16 characters
```

For example, you could do the same thing in base 10:

```
printf("%05d", 3); // output: 00003
```

You can also play with decimals:

```
printf("%.05f", 0.5); // output: 0.50000
```

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/printf/

Comment: No i wanted to know how can store my initial value 0x0706050403020100.
can i store it using character array or dynamically using malloc or using unsigned long long int ??

Comment: You can store your value anywhere where you've allocated at least 8 bytes of memory.  This could be a long (depending on the hardware), a char[8], a long double (which might actually be 16 bytes), a struct that you make, etc.

In your initial post you said your problem was that you don't see the first hex character when you output your number.  This is normal - it's just like, when you output the value 3, you often don't want to see 0000000003.  If you want leading zeroes, you have to tell printf to include them.  But I can assure you that your machine has not "forgotten" about a nybble.

Comment: I also might add that doing

char[8]="0x0706050403020100";

will probably produce a segfault, because you're declaring 8 bytes and filling it with 18.

Comment: @Rider:Thanks.But hw to tell printf to include leading zeroes.

Comment: So how should i declare using char(static or dynamically)??

Comment: To show leading zeroes, use printf like I showed you. :)

I'll edit my original post to be more specific.

Comment: I was just mentioning the char array as an example, but I doubt that a char array is the optimal solution.  If you really want to use a char array, declare your char arr[8], then read your 8-byte value into the memory pointed to by arr.  To print it, you'd then have to either loop over each char, printing each one as a zero-padded 2-digit hex value, or else cast arr as a (long *).  Depending on the hardware, you may have issues like endianness to deal with.  Like I said, probably not your ideal solution. :)