# How to generate 8 byte hex value?

Tags: c, seed, packets

I want to generate this sequential data in C:

```
data_packet[1] = 0706050403020100 (seed_value)
```

next

```
data_packet[2] = 0f0e0d0c0b0a0908
```

Next will be the next 8 hexadecimal characters and so on for say 100 bytes. How can I do it? Can we do it using character array?

Comment: And with an unedited `Blockquote`, no one will invite you to their parties.

Comment: `char data[] = "0706050403020100";` ? It's a bit hard to decode what you're actually asking.

Comment: no i wan to generate sequential data in that order.

Comment: Can you try it using a character array and see what happens?

Comment: I don't understand your question. I've looked at some of your other questions and it seems a recurring problem for you. You need to put yourself in the readers' shoes. You may even hit the answer yourself doing so.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to input 8 byte hexadecimal number into char array? ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3521079/how-to-input-8-byte-hexadecimal-number-into-char-array)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't want to use a `char` array since `char` may or may not be signed (implementation defined).  If you are playing with hexadecimal numbers from 0x00 to 0xFF, I strongly recommend using an `unsigned char` array.

Looks like the values in the array are sequential, from 0 to N.  This indicates using a `for` loop.

The array is a fixed size of 8 bytes.  Hmmm, another good candidate for a `for` loop.

The hard part of your task is the direction of the bytes.  For example are filling in the array starting at position 7 or at position 0?

So here is some psuedo code to help you along:

```
For each value from 0 to N do:
begin
  for array position from 0 to 7 do: // or from 7 to 0
    put 'value' into the array at 'position';
  call function to process the array.
end
```

For more fun, change the functionality of "put 'value'" to "put random value".

If you want us to actually write your program, let us know.  I could use the extra money. :-)